# java+jsp on tomcat 7.0.75 загрузка данных в файл

Tags: java, файлы, jsp, tomcat

Дано:

1) Есть вэб приложение которое выгребает из БД пачку значений и отображает список на страничке

сервлет.java:

```
  List<String> result;
    result =collectionMy.distinct("param2").query("param1:'somevalue1'}").as(String.class);
```

index.jsp:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <c:forEach var="result" items="${result}">
                ${result}
                <br>
            </c:forEach>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Вопрос: как с помощью данного приложения организовать сохранение значений таблицы в файл? 
Важно:

1) генерить файл при событии на странице - например жмакнуть кнопку или ссылку и предлагать юзеру его сохранить у себя.
Думал о варианте таком:

2) создавать файл по событию и отображать кнопку/ссылку на скачивание и удаление

1) и 2) варианты подходят ...

Comment: А вы уже как то пробовали решить вопрос?

Comment: Вариантов вагон: от js, формирующего необходимый формат, до state-less сервера, получающего данные страницы обратно в post запросе и выплевывающего файл. Каждый _решает_ как он хочет.... Ну и как проще, соответственною

Comment: Нет, решать не пробовал так понятия в этом весьма скромные, хотелось получить хотя бы сслыки на примеры решений подобных вопросов. Гуглинг по ключевых заводит либо в дебри тонких материй либо на примеры которые мне ну никак не помогут...